# Looking for (for the lack of a better word) Matrix Databases

Tags: scientific-computing, matrix, matlab

Is there a database engine where I can store matrices (like in math) and then perform operations.

So these would be large matrices sometimes sparse other times not.

I would basically like to perform stuff like:

1. Dot Products
2. Cross Products
3. Slicing
4. Possibly SVD

I am familiar of Matrix or scientific libraries but I'm looking for something that would help me store, process kind of like a RDBMS like MySQL does. It would be great if they distribute processing.

Thanks.

Comment: What are the things you need that RDBMS do but scientific libraries/software like Matlab/R/NumPy/etc don't?